how to find the IP address of a server that responds first among several servers using Kotlin
I am working on a decentralized network Android App. There are several servers, I need to find the server that responds the fastest to a network call. It seems easy but surprisingly hard. Any help to solve the issue using Kotlin is appreciated.
There is the current code that Gemini supplied, which unfortunately cannot return@coroutineScope. It is not allowed by the compiler. return@await is allowed, but it does not get out of the coroutineScope, so all the coroutines are waited for. It can cost 10 seconds.
suspend fun getAccessibleIP(ipList: List<String>): String? = coroutineScope {
    val deferreds = ipList.filter { isValidPublicIpAddress(it) }.map { ip ->
        Timber.tag("getAccessibleIP").d("trying $ip")
        async {
            try {
                HproseInstance.isAccessible(ip)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        withTimeoutOrNull(2000L) {
            select<String?> {
                deferreds.forEach { deferred ->
                    deferred.onAwait { res ->
                        if (res != null) {
                            // Cancel remaining deferred values and return the result
                            deferreds.forEach { it.cancel() }
                            return@coroutineScope res // Exit coroutineScope and return res
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        // Ensure all coroutines are cancelled if the function exits
        deferreds.forEach { it.cancel() }
    }
}


The simplest idiom for this, by a significant margin, is
return channelFlow {
  for (ip in ipList) {
      if (isValidPublicIpAddress(ip)) {
        Timber.tag("getAccessibleIP").d("trying $ip")
        launch {
            try {
                send(HproseInstance.isAccessible(ip))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // do nothing, I guess?
            }
        }
    }
}.firstOrNull()

Using firstOrNull will cancel all other in-progress work after the first result finishes.

When I used OkHttp to make the network call, the coroutine seemed to get stuck and never returned. However, when I switched to Ktor, it worked like a charm. The fastest coroutine returned, and the others got cancelled.
